# raspbian stretch 1609 manual update with 1804 binary installer does not work

Tags: ejabberd

i tried to install 1804 parallel to the 1609 stretch package, that works, but i can't restore the old database, i get this error:

$ ./ejabberdctl restore /var/lib/ejabberd/ejabberd.backup
Can't restore backup from "/var/lib/ejabberd/ejabberd.backup" at node ejabberd@raspberrypi: Table config does not exist."

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can simply copy the old spool directory to the new location. When ejabberd starts, it detects a database with old schema, and updates whatever required.